# Calculate pair occurrences

Tags: php, arrays, string, combinations

Let's say I have the following string:

```
foo,bar,baz
bar,foo
quux,baz,foo
```

I'd like to generate a list of pairs to occur more than one so you'll get the following array:

```
[['foo', 'bar'], ['foo', 'baz']],
```

Maybe this sounds silly, but I've been banging my head for some time now on how to do this. Another problem is that the set is a couple of MB's large and, if possible the code needs to be very efficient.

Can anyone push me in the right direction?
Maybe with some kind of algorithm for efficiency or just some sample code?

Comment: Are the terms always separated by comma's?

Comment: rows with \n and terms with a comma

Comment: This isn't a trivial task, so I don't know if directly asking for an efficient solution is the right course here. You know what you want (aka expected output), so try to come up with a solution first (after all - that is what programming is about) and worry about efficiency later

Comment: Well, you have to create all existing pairs, sort them alphabetically internal and then group them to find the number of occurrences for each. If you then remove all with occurrence 1 you should have your result.

Comment: This question is lacking a [mcve] and as a consequence is Unclear.  It might also be considered Too Broad and may also be closed as Needing More Focus because there is no code and no pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

Divide and conquer.

Prepare list of all pairs of one line and then concatenate all lines list of pairs and find out those repeating.

```
$string = <<<STRING
foo,bar,baz
bar,foo
quux,baz,foo
STRING;

$lines = array_map(function ($line) {
    // split lines into words
    $words = explode(',', $line);

    // filter repeats
    $words = array_unique($words);

    // sort words
    sort($words);

    return $words;
}, preg_split('/\R/', $string));

function pairs($words) {
    $length = count($words);

    if ($length < 2) {
        throw new Exception('No pairs if length < 2');
    }

    $pairs = [];

    // iterate from start to one before last word
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length - 1; $i++) {
        // iterate from next word to end
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $length; $j++) {
            $pairs[] = [$words[$i], $words[$j]];
        }
    }

    return $pairs;
}

$allPairs = [];
$nonUniquePairs = [];
foreach ($lines as $words) {
    $pairs = pairs($words);
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        // check if pair is already added and not in $nonUniquePairs array
        if (in_array($pair, $allPairs, true) && !in_array($pair, $nonUniquePairs, true)) {
            $nonUniquePairs[] = $pair;
        }
    }

    $allPairs = array_unique(array_merge($allPairs, $pairs), SORT_REGULAR);
}
```

And this will be the results:

```
'allPairs' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'bar' (length=3)
          1 => string 'baz' (length=3)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'bar' (length=3)
          1 => string 'foo' (length=3)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'baz' (length=3)
          1 => string 'foo' (length=3)
      4 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'baz' (length=3)
          1 => string 'quux' (length=4)
      5 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'foo' (length=3)
          1 => string 'quux' (length=4)
'nonUniquePairs' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'bar' (length=3)
          1 => string 'foo' (length=3)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'baz' (length=3)
          1 => string 'foo' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$str = 'foo,bar,baz,baz,b
bar,foo,b,a
quux,b,baz,foo,a';


// prepare a working array    
$array = array_map(function ($i) { return array_unique(array_map('trim', explode(',', $i))); }, explode("\n", $str));

// find intersects of all arrays
$res = array();
for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++)
   for($j=$i+1; $j < count($array); $j++) {
       $temp = array_unique(array_intersect($array[$i], $array[$j]));
       sort($temp);     // Reaet indexes
       $res[] = $temp;
       } 

// Gather unique pairs
$pairs = array();
foreach($res as $item) 
   for($i=0; $i < count($item); $i++)
      for($j=$i+1; $j < count($item); $j++) {
          $c = true;
          foreach($pairs as $p)
              if(!array_diff($p, array($item[$i], $item[$j]))) {
                 $c = false; 
                 break;
                 }
         if($c) $pairs[] = array($item[$i], $item[$j]);
         }
print_r($pairs);
```

result

```
[ [b, bar], [b, foo], [bar, foo], [b, baz], [baz, foo], [a,b], [a, foo] ]
```

[**Demo on eval**](https://eval.in/412539)